# ¿Cómo ordenar una oración alfabéticamente sin contar los caracteres no alfabéticos?

Tags: c, ordenamiento

Quisiera saber como podría ordenar una oración alfabéticamente sin contar los espacios, comas y puntos. Intenté utilizar el método de burbuja pero aun asi cuenta lo antes mencionado. Espero y me puedan ayudar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char texto[105];
    char aux[105];
    fgets(texto, 105, stdin);
    int longitud = strlen(texto);
    for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < longitud - 1; j++)
        {
           if (texto[j] > texto[j + 1])
           {
            aux[0] = texto[j];
            texto[j] = texto[j + 1];
            texto[j + 1] = aux[0];
           }
        }
    }
    printf("%s", texto);        
    return 0;
 }
```

Un ejemplo de la entrada y salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si yo uso `pepito juanito,juan`, la salida es `,aaeiijjnnooppttuu`. Lo que no se entiende en tu pregunta es: debería ignorarlos? ponerlos al final?

Comment: Por ejemplo si yo uso la siguiente oración: "hola gatito,perrito adios" la salida debería de ser la siguiente: "aaad eghiii,loooopr rsttt", osea que los puntos, comas y espacios se mantengan en su posición original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manteniendo tu código y lógica solo vamos hacer algunas modificaciones que consisten principalmente en:

1. Creamos un arreglo igual al del texto
2. En este nuevo arreglo pasaremos todas las letras del texto
3. Ordenamos el nuevo arreglo
4. Pasamos el nuevo arreglo al texto
5. Mostramos el texto ordenado conservando los espacios y comas

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
    int main()
    {
        char texto[105];
        // 1. Creamos un arreglo similar
        char txt[105] = { 0 };
        char aux[105];
        fgets(texto, 105, stdin);
        int longitud = strlen(texto);
        int n = 0;
        // 2. Pasamos solo letras al nuevo arreglo
        for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {
            if (isalpha(texto[i])) {
                txt[n++] = texto[i];
           }
        }

        // 3. Ordenamos el nuevo arreglo
 
        longitud = strlen(txt);

        for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < longitud - 1; j++)
            {
                if (txt[j] > txt[j + 1])
                {
                    aux[0] = txt[j];
                    txt[j] = txt[j + 1];
                    txt[j + 1] = aux[0];
                }
            }
        }
        
        // 4. Pasamos el arreglo ordenado al texto
        longitud = strlen(texto);
        n = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {
            if (isalpha(texto[i])) {
                texto[i] = txt[n++];
            }
        }
        // 5. Mostramos el resultado 
        printf("%s\n", texto);

        return 0;
    }
```

Espero sea lo que querias hacer.